# Determine number of variables of a inline function in Matlab

Tags: matlab, parameter-passing, inline, anonymous-function

I would like to write a function like this:

```
function foo(goo,...)
  if( goo is a function of two variables )
    % do something
  else
    % do something else
  end
end
```

Is there any way I can get the number of variables of a inline function (or of an anonymous function?). To make it more clear:

```
f = inline('x + y')
g = inline('x')
```

I want to be able to distinguish that f is a function of two variables and g of 1 variable

Comment: See the [`nargin`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargin.html) function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

**EDIT**

After I answered this, a better strategy has been found: Just use `nargin`; see [@k-messaoudi's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23565163/2586922).

---

**For inline functions**:

According to `inline`'s help:

> INLINE(EXPR) constructs an inline function object from the MATLAB expression contained in the string EXPR.  The input arguments are automatically determined by searching EXPR
>       for variable names (see SYMVAR).

Therefore: call [`symvar`](http://www.mathworks.es/es/help/matlab/ref/symvar.html) and see how many elements it returns:

```
>> f = inline('x + y');
>> g = inline('x');
>> numel(symvar(f))
ans =
     2
>> numel(symvar(g))
ans =
     1
```

**For anonymous functions**:

First use `functions` to get information about the anonymous function:

```
>> f = @(x,y,z) x+y+z;
>> info = functions(f)
info = 
     function: '@(x,y,z)x+y+z'
         type: 'anonymous'
         file: ''
    workspace: {[1x1 struct]}
```

Now, again use `symvar` on `info.function`:

```
>> numel(symvar(info.function))
ans =
     3
```

Answer (score 2):

define your variables : `syms x1 x2 x3 .... xn;`

define your function : `f = inline(x1 + x2 + sin(x3) + ... );`

number of input  argument : `n_arg = nargin(f)`

number of output argument : `n_arg = nargout(f)`

Comment: Rather add this to your original answer (i.e. edit the answer) and then delete this now redundant answer.